# "contains possible faulty output" or "contains potential faulty output"?

Tags: sentence-patterns

Is there any difference between saying this? I'm using this to report system output that might contain output that is worth investigating for the maintainers.

Comment: _Potential_ sounds strange here. If the system contains output, then that output can’t be potential – it’s factual (but **does** it contain output necessarily?). _Possible_ sounds less strange, though it obviously suffers from the same logical flaw. Why not just “May contain faulty output”? Perhaps the most logical and simple option would be “Output may be contain errors” – but that only works if it actually matches what the system is, of course. If there may be no output at all, it won’t work.

Comment: *faulty output* suggests that the system output was supposed to contain “An error occurred in module 17’ but instead contained “An $87$& snje fj in wnfncj 17.”  What you really want to say is that the system output may contain evidence of a system fault.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> “contains possible faulty output” or “contains potential faulty
>   output”?

I suggest:

“possibly contains faulty output” or “potentially contains faulty output”

In these usages, and in your context, possible and potential are of a similar sense, and are synonymous!  [TFD](https://www.freethesaurus.com/potential)